# React Router: Component doesn't update on route change after login/logout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm working on a React application that utilizes React Router for routing and has an authentication system. After logging in or logging out, the route changes correctly, but the component doesn't update/render until I manually refresh the page. Additionally, after logging out, a blank screen appears on the login route until I manually refresh the page, and then the login screen appears.

I've already tried the following:

- Ensuring that the AuthProvider component wraps the entire
  application, including the routing.
- Adding a unique key to the
  rendered component in the protected route.
- Clearing the token from
  the localStorage upon logout.

Below is my code snippet

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/admin" component={AdminDashboard} />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </AuthProvider>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

**PrivateRouter.js**

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component key={props.location.key} {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

**Login.js**

```
  const history = useHistory();
  const { isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    // Perform login logic, e.g., validate email and password
    // Assuming successful login for demonstration purposes
    localStorage.setItem("token", "your_token_here");
    setIsAuthenticated(true);

    console.log(isAuthenticated);
    history.replace("home");
  };
  return ( // jsx here // )
```

Unfortunately, none of these solutions have resolved the issue. I've also created a live demo on StackBlitz to showcase the problem. You can access it here: https://stackblitz.com/github/mehulk05/react-auth?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FLogin.jsx

Github: https://github.com/mehulk05/react-auth

Can anyone please help me understand why the component doesn't update/render on route changes after login/logout, and why the login screen only appears after refreshing the page? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code in your stackblitz appears to be working correctly as I'd expect and as you describe wanting it to work. I don't see it reproducing the issue you describe. After clicking "log in" the app sets the state and redirects to `"/home"` with what appears to be the correct UI. Same with logging out.

Comment: In my opinion you can add a loading state to manage your routes as when you login, changes aren't immediately visible and react still takes  the old state and it doesn't find any token so it redirectss you to the same page i.e login page.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is probably due to the fact that setting state is asynchronous, so the changes aren't immediately visible. You call setIsAuthenticated(true), but when you immediately log isAuthenticated, it still logs the old value. The new value isn't available until the next render, after React has updated the state.

This might also explain why your routes aren't updating immediately. The ProtectedRoute component checks isAuthenticated, but the value hasn't updated yet because the state update is still pending.

One possible solution to this is using the useEffect hook. You could set up a side effect that watches the isAuthenticated value and updates the route when the value changes.

```
  const Login = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated } = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      history.replace("/home");
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated]); // This effect runs whenever `isAuthenticated` changes

  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    // Perform login logic, e.g., validate email and password
    // Assuming successful login for demonstration purposes
    localStorage.setItem("token", "your_token_here");
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
  };

  return ( /* JSX here */ );
}
```